# Wrong Routing Django

Tags: django, django-views

[I have a Django project with this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPUwl.png)

in baseApp views.py

```
def Home(request):
    rooms = Room.objects.all()
    context = {'rooms':rooms}
    return render(request,'base/home.html',context)

def room(request,pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'room':room}
    return render(request,'base/room.html',context)

def createRoom(request):
    context= {}
    return render(request,'base/room_form.html',context)
```

in baseApp urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Home, name="home page"),
    path('<pk>/', views.room, name="room"),
    path('create-room/',views.createRoom, name="create-room"),
]
```

in the base/temp/home.html

```
<h2> <a href="{% url 'create-room' %}">Create Room</a></h2>
```

in room_form.html

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div>
    <form method="=Post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>


    </div>

{% endblock content%}
```

it supposed to go to to this url : 172.0.0.1:8000/create-room/ " to room_form.html"
but it goes to : 172.0.0.1:8000/room/create-room  with error
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create-room'

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2055, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create-room') was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/chatroom/base/views.py", line 23, in room
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 623, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1436, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1454, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1461, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1498, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1529, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1444, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1271, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 341, in get_prep_lookup
    return super().get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 85, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/kotp/Desktop/python/P_project/pvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2057, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(

Exception Type: ValueError at /create-room/
Exception Value: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create-room'.
```

I am Expecting
it supposed to go to to this url : 172.0.0.1:8000/create-room/
showing room-form.html

Comment: Can you add your room_form.html please?

Comment: Can you add the track trace as well please? Does this error happen when you click your create-room link in home.html?

Comment: Does this error happen when you click your create-room link in home.html? YES

Answer (score 0):

It will not "fire" the `createRoom`, you did not specify the type of the `pk`, so it takes [**`<str:…>`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), so that means that `create-room/` will take `pk='create-room'`.

You can specify the type as [**`<int:…>`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Home, name='home-page'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('create-room/', views.createRoom, name='create-room'),
]
```

Comment: it worked half way ,I can see the create room page but wrong url

Comment: @Ahmed: likely you used an include, and therefore the `/room` prefix is valid.